# Framer Motion Snap on DragEnd

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have built a carousel that scrolls on drag with framer motion but want it to snap to centre each new slide when released. Is this possible? I can't find anything in the docs surprisingly.

It works when I press button but seems to be an issue with responding when dragging or just after dragging.

```
const BannnerCarousel = ({ slice }) => {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
    const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
    const [ref, { width: slideWidth }] = useMeasure();

const carousel = useRef();

const x = useMotionValue(0);

let totalSlides = slice?.items?.length - 1;
const speed = slice?.primary?.speed || 8; // carousel auto slide speed in seconds

const handleSlideSnap = () => {
    x.set(-slideWidth * currentSlide);
};

const nextSlide = useCallback(() => {
    if (currentSlide === totalSlides) {
        setCurrentSlide(0);
    } else {
        setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 1);
    }
}, [currentSlide, totalSlides]);

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => nextSlide(), speed * 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [nextSlide, speed]);

useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(carousel.current.scrollWidth - carousel.current.offsetWidth);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    handleSlideSnap();
}, [currentSlide, handleSlideSnap]);

return (
    <section>
        <motion.div
            ref={carousel}
            whileTap={{ cursor: 'grabbing' }}
            className='overflow-hidden cursor-grab'
        >
            <motion.div
                drag='x'
                dragConstraints={{ right: 0, left: -width }}
                style={{ x }}
                onDragEnd={handleSlideSnap}
                className='flex'
            >
                {slice.items.map((item, i) => (
                    <div key={i} className='relative'>
                        {item.image && (
                            <motion.div
                                ref={ref}
                                viewport={{ amount: 0.5 }}
                                onViewportEnter={() => setCurrentSlide(i)}
                                className='relative min-h-[500px] md:min-h-[600px] w-screen'
                            >
                                <Image
                                    src={item.image.url}
                                    alt={item.image?.alt || item?.title}
                                    layout='fill'
                                    objectFit='cover'
                                    priority={i === 0 ? true : false}
                                />
                            </motion.div>
                        )}
                        <div className='absolute inset-0 w-full min-h-[500px] bg-black/60 md:min-h-[600px] flex items-end pt-24 pb-20'>
                            <div className='container h-full'>
                                <div className='w-full h-full xl:w-1/2 flex flex-col justify-end'>
                                    {item.title && (
                                        <span className='block font-nunito font-extrabold text-2xl sm:text-3xl md:text-5xl text-white mb-4 uppercase leading-relaxed sm:leading-relaxed md:leading-snug text-center sm:text-start'>
                                            <PrismicRichText field={item.title} />
                                        </span>
                                    )}
                                    {item.description && (
                                        <span className='block font-source-serif-pro text-lg sm:text-xl md:text-2xl text-white mb-8 text-center sm:text-start leading-relaxed sm:leading-relaxed md:leading-relaxed'>
                                            <PrismicRichText field={item.description} />
                                        </span>
                                    )}
                                    {item.link && (
                                        <span className='flex justify-center sm:justify-start relative z-10'>
                                            <PrismicLink field={item.link}>
                                                <span className='mx-auto flex font-source-serif-pro font-semibold text-base sm:text-xl md:text-2xl button'>
                                                    <PrismicRichText field={item?.buttonText} />
                                                </span>
                                            </PrismicLink>
                                        </span>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </motion.div>
        </motion.div>

        <div className='flex gap-4 justify-center my-10 w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 mx-auto'>
            {slice?.items?.map((item, i) => (
                <button
                    key={i}
                    aria-label={`Go to slide ${i + 1}`}
                    onClick={() => setCurrentSlide(i)}
                    style={{ width: `calc(100%/${totalSlides})` }}
                    className={`h-2 ${
                        currentSlide === i ? 'bg-secondary-100' : 'bg-gray-400'
                    } transition-colors`}
                ></button>
            ))}
        </div>
    </section>
);
```

};

export default BannnerCarousel;

Answer (score -1):

Use this: https://www.framer.com/docs/gestures/###dragsnaptoorigin
Just change the origin on `dragEnd`